# Make a sugar cube look squashed inside a room and getting rid of the glow around it

Tags: modeling, rendering, geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a sugar cube look squashed inside a room but I'm finding difficulty in getting rid of the glow around the object

[image]

I made the sugar cube by looking at BlenderGuru's video as I am new to Blender.

Comment: The "glow" looks like you are using a volume in the EEVEE render engine (which is the default engine in material preview mode, which you are in). Volume objects do not adhere to mesh surfaces in EEVEE, so the volume fills a bounding box for the object, instead of the object itself. To make the volume appear properly, switch to Cycles render engine (or if you are already using cycles, press Z in the 3D viewport and select "rendered" from the pie menu to enter render preview mode.)

Comment: Thank you that worked.